# Toggle covering a div with semi-transparent component

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am wondering how to cover a `<div>` with some useful HTML component/image to make the `<div>`:

- A) Unclickable (unreachable for mouse etc)
- B) Look a little ~0.3f blur (because of it transparent foreground)
- C) make the effect dynamic I mean make the `<div>` covered/uncovered by some
  event?

So my question is: What is the optimal way to make the previously mentioned effect with HTML, CSS, and Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(A) Making the div "Unclickable (unreachable for mouse etc)"*

This can be accomplished by using the various [CSS positioning elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/css-positioning.html) to place two divs in the exact same location. Then to stack one div on top of the other, use [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index) (the element with the higher `z-index` will be stacked on top of the element with the lower `z-index`). For example:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1, #div2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

#div2 {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

---

*(B) Making the div "Look a little ~0.3f blur (because of it transparent foreground)"*

To do this, you would use CSS [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/opacity). For example:

```
#div2 {
    opacity: .3;
}
```

---

*(C) "Make the effect dynamic I mean make the  covered/uncovered by some event."*

You can accomplish this using Javascript. The simplest approach would probably be to use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) to add [`display:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display) to the div you want to remove.

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

---

**NOTE**: These are not the only ways to accomplish this task. I am just trying to give you a launching point.  I recommend reviewing the MDN links I posted and writing code that works best for what you are specifically trying to accomplish.

Comment: So the 'z-index: 1;' must be changed dynamically then? From 1 to 2 and back with JS? I am not pretty sure how to access CSS with JS in this case could you give a little more details here?

Comment: And I wanted to ask what if div1 and div2 are both placed into 'lets say a' div0 for example? Will the sample code work in this case?

Comment: See my edits. The `z-index` only pertains to stacking the element on the z-axis; i.e. which one you will "see" when two divs of the same size are in the same location.

Comment: Yes, they will work the same if they are in another div, just as they work now within the body tag. Also, keep in mind that these are just one way to approach this task. I recommend reading more on positioning, z-index, and opacity to write code that works best for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you it is quite interesting idea... I am to ask concerning this line as 'document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';' as I could get it the thing was A) Have div1 and div2 in div0 B) change div1 or div2 layers index(s) (z-location) related to div0... so I am not pretty sure what '...style.display' here about?

Comment: See my updated answer. You would use the javascript to turn off the display of an element; i.e. essentially make it disappear. It's regular value is `display:inline`; so if you wanted to toggle the div back you would use the same approach but change "none" to "inline".

Comment: So is there a way to change z-index dynamically for div1 and div2? I mean not to remove any every time but put them on sub/sup layers?

Comment: Ok Thanks :) Basically I got the conception